# Ending my RPS game?

Tags: java

I have my RPS program down pretty well. I'm still trying to learn about while loops, and I'm not sure what to do on ending my game. Everything works, until I give an invalid answer on "yes or no" when it asks me if I'd like to play again. If I say yes, it starts the game back over as it should, BUT when I say no after being prompted to try again after a prior invalid answer, it plays again as if i were saying yes. I'm new to this and haven't been to class due to sickness. How would I go about solving this? I want it to loop back to the original outcomes of "yes" and "no" The first snipped is my issue, the second is the code itself:

```
Would you like to play again? (yes or no)
nah
Error! Invalid response. Try again:
no
Welcome to the Rock - Paper - Scissors Game!

Please enter your selection (Rock, Paper, or Scissors): 



Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   Random generator = new Random();
   String computerChoice;
   String user;
   String playerChoice;
   boolean keepPlaying = true;
   int playerWins = 0;
   int playerTies = 0;
   int playerLosses = 0;
   int roundTotal = 0;
   int computer;
   while (keepPlaying == true) {
   System.out.println("Welcome to the Rock - Paper - Scissors Game!");
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("Please enter your selection (Rock, Paper, or Scissors): ");
   playerChoice = scan.next();
   playerChoice = playerChoice.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+ playerChoice.substring(1).toLowerCase();
   computer = generator.nextInt(3)+1;
   if(computer == 1) 
   {
       computerChoice = "Rock"; 
   }
    else if(computer == 2) 
   {
       computerChoice = "Paper"; 
   }
    else if (computer == 3) 
   {
       computerChoice = "Scissors";
   }
    else
    {
       computerChoice = "Rock";
    }

   System.out.println("User: " +playerChoice);
   System.out.println("Comp: " +computerChoice);
   if(computer==1 && playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock"))
   {
      System.out.println("Match Outcome -> User Ties");
      roundTotal++;
      playerTies++;
   }
   else if(computer==2 && playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("paper"))
   {
      System.out.println("Match Outcome -> User Ties");
      roundTotal++;
      playerTies++;
   }
   else if(computer==3 && playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors"))
   {
      System.out.println("Match Outcome -> User Ties");
      roundTotal++;
      playerTies++;
   }
   else if(computer==1 && playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors"))
   {
      System.out.println("Match Outcome -> User Loses");
      roundTotal++;
      playerLosses++;
   }
   else if(computer==1 && playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("paper"))
   {
      System.out.println("Match Outcome -> User Wins");
      roundTotal++;
      playerWins++;
   }
   else if(computer==2 && playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock"))
   {
      System.out.println("Match Outcome -> User Loses");
      roundTotal++;
      playerLosses++;
   }
   else if(computer==2 && playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors"))
   {
      System.out.println("Match Outcome -> User Wins");
      roundTotal++;
      playerWins++;
   }
   else if(computer==3 && playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock"))
   {
      System.out.println("Match Outcome -> User Wins");
      roundTotal++;
      playerWins++;
   }
   else if(computer==3 && playerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("paper"))
   {
      System.out.println("Match Outcome -> User Loses");
      roundTotal++;
      playerLosses++;
   }
   else {
      System.out.println("Error! Invalid response.");
   }
   String response = "";
   System.out.println("Would you like to play again? (yes or no)");
   response = scan.next();
   if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
   {
      keepPlaying = false;
      System.out.println("Out of " +roundTotal+ " total rounds, the user had " +playerWins+ " total wins, " +playerLosses+ " total loses, and " +playerTies+ " total ties.");
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
   }
   else if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
   {
      keepPlaying = true;
   }
   else while (!response.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && !response.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
   {
   System.out.println("Error! Invalid response. Try again:");
      response = scan.next();
   }
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is here:

```
else while (!response.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && !response.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
   System.out.println("Error! Invalid response. Try again:");
   response = scan.next();
}
```

Once the first response isn't a "yes" or a "no", you end up in this `else` clause. Here, you read the responses until you get a "yes" or a "no" but once you got a valid response, you don't do anything with it, so you just return to the main loop, starting a new game.

You could fix it by rewriting the last part of your code like this:

```
String response = "";
System.out.println("Would you like to play again? (yes or no)");
do {
    response = scan.next();
    if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
        keepPlaying = false;
            System.out.println("Out of " + roundTotal + " total rounds, the user had " + playerWins
                        + " total wins, " + playerLosses + " total loses, and " + playerTies + " total ties.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
    } else {
        if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            keepPlaying = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error! Invalid response. Try again:");
        }
    }
} while (!response.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && !response.equalsIgnoreCase("no"));
```